# "Нести главенствующее значение" - можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Эстетика <ранних христианских церквей> первых веков нашей эры была взрощена тайными службами, где
>   знак или символ несли главенствующее значение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как это можно понять:

**Эстетика <ранних христианских церквей> первых веков нашей эры была взращена тайными службами, где знак или символ несли** (= передавали, содержали)  **главенствующее** (= основное)  **значение** (= христианского учения).

ГЛАВЕНСТВУЮЩИЙ — основной, ведущий, господствующий.

Почему —  ***взрОщена***?  В [**словаре ударений**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_udarenie/4752) правильно так:
*взращённый, взращён, **взращена́**, взращено́, взращены́.*

Comment: В таком смысе так действительно можно написать. Но это ли хотел сказать автор? Сомневаюсь.

Comment: Жасмин, спасибо за ***взрОщена*** (и вообще, когда видишь орфографию, - кричи!) - это я прозевала, увлечённая тайными смыслами...

Comment: @Jasmin При оценке Вашего ответа (естественно, +10) я позволила себе внести в него коррективы и  ту ссылку, на которую Вы указывали.

Comment: Спасибо, ничего не имею против, просто иногда нет времени для хорошего оформления.

Answer (score 2):

Нести (символу, иероглифу, термину) можно **смысловое** значение (такое-то), как и смысл (нести в себе). Значение же, о котором говорится, является не смысловым, а "весовым", **сопоставительным** по величине (значимости) с чем-то. Большее или меньшее значение (вплоть до главенствующего) - *имеют* (по сравнению с чем-то другим или всем остальным),  но не "несут".

Answer (score 2):

«Эстетика <ранних христианских церквей> первых веков нашей эры была взрощена тайными службами, где знак или символ несли главенствующее значение.»

Ранние христианские церкви возникли в конце IV в., и эти столетия нельзя назвать первыми. *Тайные службы* смахивают на карательную структуру, а не собор, поэтому лучше так: тайное служение. *Главенствующее* значение знака — очень сильно, т. к. они (символы) были неким пропуском в тайное сообщество и не более.

*Эстетика <ранних христианских церквей> была под стать таинственности первых служений веруюших в начале лет от Р. Х., когда всякий знак получал своё особое —  символическое значение.*

Answer (score 0):

Проговорил вслух. Очень сильно бьёт по ушам. Значение можно присвоить, назначить, иметь, но нести? То же самое касается и сочетания "главенствующее значение". Важное - да, а вот "главенствующее" - никак, на мой взгляд :)

Comment: "Главенствующее значение" хорошо гуглится, а с глаголом напряжёнка.